# Read line by line from text file and save to database

Tags: c#

Here is my code:

```
List<string> myValues = new List<string>();

string line;

StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"D:\a.txt");
if ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] fields = line.Split(',');
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=NT;Initial Catalog=SinhVien;Integrated Security=True"))
    {

        con.Open();
        while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Sinhvien(ID, HoTen, DiaChi) VALUES (@id, @hoten, @diachi)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", fields[0].ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hoten", fields[1].ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@diachi", fields[2].ToString());
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

}
```

And my text file is:

```
10,Hong,10 hung vuong

11,Thuy,11 Hung Vuong

22,Thanh,22 Hung Vuong
```

But i can't save all line to database?

Comment: You are beginning with the second line, is that desired? You are also splitting the fields only once not for every line (move it into the loop).

Comment: Which lines can't you save to the database? Do they just not appear there or do you get an error? Question is quite unclear as it stands.

Comment: I'm guessing you're saving the same data 2 times?

Comment: First line, but i don't know how

Comment: @jonesopolis: You right! I don't want like that

Comment: The `if` statement reads a line that you don't use, that's where your first line is vanishing.

Comment: (1) Move `string[] fields = line.Split(',');` before `SqlCommand cmd = ...`. (2) Change `while (...) { ... }` to `do { ...} while(...);`

Comment: @DavidG: All line must be save to database. But first line save and loop line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you're looping *after* you declare your fields, and never reset them.  You want to loop through your file,get the fields, and save them in each iteration:

```
string line;

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=NT;Initial Catalog=SinhVien;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    con.Open();
    using(StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"D:\a.txt"))
    {
         while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
         {
             string[] fields = line.Split(',');

             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Sinhvien(ID, HoTen, DiaChi) VALUES (@id, @hoten, @diachi)", con);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", fields[0].ToString());
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hoten", fields[1].ToString());
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@diachi", fields[2].ToString());
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
    }
}
```

`StreamReader` implements `IDisposable`, so it advisable you wrap it in a `using` statement as well.

Answer (score 2):

You're not too far off. Let's simplify this:

```
// If the file is small, read it all at once
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\a.txt");

// TODO: if lines is empty, bail out

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=NT;Initial Catalog=SinhVien;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    con.Open();
    // for each line (no ifs or whiles here)
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        string[] fields = line.Split(',');
        // TODO: verify fields contain what you want
        // SqlCommand implements IDisposable too
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Sinhvien(ID, HoTen, DiaChi) VALUES (@id, @hoten, @diachi)", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", fields[0]); // these are already strings, no ToString()s needed
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hoten", fields[1]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@diachi", fields[2]);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

If your source file is rather large, and need to stream the lines out of it, then the other answerer shows that approach.